# nullpointerexception when activity is trying to communicate with bounded service

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-service, android-service-binding

I am trying to make my activity communicate with a running background service, but keeps getting a NullPointerException, which doesn't make any sense.. for me at least. Hope someone else can figure out what the problem might be.

First here is my LogCat output:

```
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at com.takenumber.TakeNumber.sendMessageToService(TakeNumber.java:240)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at com.takenumber.TakeNumber$2.onClick(TakeNumber.java:334)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
03-17 20:16:56.390: E/AndroidRuntime(11563):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What I do in my activity:

is to start the service and bind it:

```
                    serviceIntent = new Intent(context, ServerService.class);                   
                    serviceIntent.putExtra("messageType", StaticValues.MESSAGE_START_SERVICE); 
                    serviceIntent.putExtra("devicetype", StaticValues.DEVICE_TAKENUMBER); 
                    serviceIntent.putExtra("MESSENGER", new Messenger(messageHandler));
                    startService(serviceIntent);
                    bindService(serviceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

and create a serviceConnection:

```
private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
            if (isServer) {
                boundServiceServer = ((ServerService.CustomBinder) service).getService();
            } else {
                boundServiceClient = ((ClientService.CustomBinder) service).getService();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            boundServiceClient = null;
            boundServiceServer = null;
        }
    };
```

And then I have a click listener for a button to call a method in my service:

```
categoryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            Button buttonClicked = (Button)v;
                            int categoryID = v.getId();
                            String categoryTitle = buttonClicked.getText().toString();

                            // TODO: Change to send only to showline devices
                            boundServiceServer.getMessagesFromUI(StaticValues.MESSAGE_NUMBER_TAKEN + StaticValues.MESSAGE_DELIMITER + categoryID + StaticValues.MESSAGE_DELIMITER + categoryTitle);

                        }
                    });
```

In my service I do this:
Create a "`binder`":

```
public class CustomBinder extends Binder {
    public ServerService getService() {
        return ServerService.this;
    }
}
```

The method `getMessagesFromUI()` in my service (to receive strings from activity) simply looks like this:

```
public void getMessagesFromUI(String message) {
    // DO stuff
}
```

Of course `onBind()` method os overridden:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return binder;
}
```

I really hope someone can figure out the problem as I am completely lost right now.
If you need more informatione, just ask.

Edit: `Line 240 (NullPointerException)` is this one:

```
boundServiceServer.getMessagesFromUI(messageString);
```

**Additional info:**

I've pasted some of my code on pastebin on the following adresses.

The TakeNumber activity is here:
http://pastebin.com/DxrWfEYM

And the ServerService is here:
http://pastebin.com/7QjiQbTi

I have also inserted "syso"'s in the code to find out what's going on. THis is the logcat output after this:

```
03-18 14:23:05.740: D/dalvikvm(20260): GC_CONCURRENT freed 213K, 16% free 4276K/5064K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 24ms
03-18 14:23:05.790: I/System.out(20260): server connecting
03-18 14:23:05.810: I/System.out(20260): onBind
03-18 14:23:05.830: D/libEGL(20260): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
03-18 14:23:05.840: D/libEGL(20260): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
03-18 14:23:05.840: D/libEGL(20260): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
03-18 14:23:05.890: D/OpenGLRenderer(20260): Enabling debug mode 0
03-18 14:23:05.910: I/System.out(20260): server binding
03-18 14:23:05.910: I/System.out(20260): CustomBinder
03-18 14:23:13.710: I/System.out(20260): trying to send to server
03-18 14:23:13.720: D/AndroidRuntime(20260): Shutting down VM
03-18 14:23:13.720: W/dalvikvm(20260): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41954930)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at com.takenumber.TakeNumber.sendMessageToService(TakeNumber.java:244)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at com.takenumber.TakeNumber$2.onClick(TakeNumber.java:339)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
03-18 14:23:13.720: E/AndroidRuntime(20260):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The app crashes after the button is called, when I try to send data to the service.

Comment: which of those lines is `TakeNumber.sendMessageToService(TakeNumber.java:240)`?

Comment: Of course, sorry! I added it to the question

Comment: that tends to indicate that `boundServiceServer` is null.

Comment: are you sure the service is bound ?

Comment: Well now that you ask, im not absolutely sure. Is there a good way to find out if it is bound?

Comment: you could have a log in `onServiceConnected` for testing, and usually a flag is used to indicate the binding is done.

Comment: Perhaps the service itself is crashing when you fire it up.  Look for a stack trace further back in the log that might indicate that happened.

Comment: Use a break-point and debug your code to see if the member boundServiceServer is set correctly in the 'onServiceConnected' method.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate your inputs. I have tried some of the different things you've suggested (debugging etc.) and still getting the same exception (and app crash).. Now i have posted my code for both the activity and the service on pastebin (check the answer). I hope someone is up for it and will give it a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to a solution myself. I have posted my activity and service code on pastebin.

The Activity:
http://pastebin.com/jMgraK2r

The ServerService:
http://pastebin.com/yquZAi2i

For some reason, the messenger object from the activity to the service was setting itself to null somehow.
By declaring it as static, the problem was solved.

I hope anyone can learn anything from this.
Thanks to all the responses above.